# Spring SpEl - Identify which part of an expression to trigger the rule

Tags: spring, spring-el

Is there a way to identify which part of a SpEL expression trigger a rule ?

For example :

```
a < 10 || a > 20
```

I want to know if the rule is fired because `a < 10` or `a > 20`

---

For example :

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(rule.getExpression());
return Boolean.TRUE.equals(expression.getValue(evaluationContext, Boolean.class));
```

thanks to this I can know if the whole expression is true or false, in addition to this I would like to know more precisely that it has triggered the rule

Comment: Provide more informations if you really expect a response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is no way to check it using the SPeL API. But you can modify your code (if its possible) slightly and split this expression into a list of expressions `List<Expression>`, so you will be able to iterate through the list of expressions and save the result of each. I hope this idea helps you somehow

Here is example code:

```java
Map<Expression, Boolean> results = List.of(new Expression("a < 1"), new Expression("a > 20"))
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Expression::evaluate));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I think it won’t be very practical to manage